# Asynchronous Request make for-Loop waiting for didFinishLoading

Tags: iphone, for-loop, nsurlconnection, wait

I have a asynchronous url request within a for loop. This loop is called 20 times, each time one parameter of the webaddress is changed.
Everytime the didFinishLoading method is called I want to hand over the data of this specific webadress.

The problem now is that when I run the for loop, the didFinishLoading method is not called, only at the end.

Any suggenstions on how to make the loop wait for complete loading the data for the specific URL?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. some code would help.. are you using NSUrlRequest to make the calls? If so.. you can just release the object and recreate the object with the delegate at each pass of the loop...
Can take a look if some code can be posted.